# Trying to create a "like" system similar to Facebook

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, facebook, facebook-like

I am using a PHP array to gather user input that has been added to my MySQL database. As this is information from user input I am using a variable created by the num_rows in my database to determine the number of times a for loop runs through displaying my array values. The for loop contains a form that displays one value of the array, and a "like" button (type=submit), and repeats this form until all values have been displayed (from newest to oldest), with a "like" button following each.

I want users to be able to click the "like" button, to add a "like" to that post. The problem I've run into is that the code I have is adding a "like" to every post (because the code checks to see if the "like" button has been pressed, and since the "like" button was created by the for loop, every "like" button has the same name). I've tried to rectify this by giving the "like" button a name based on an incremented variable, but the button does not seem to work if the name is a variable or an array.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$userside = $_SESSION['side'];

echo "<b>Organized posts:</br><hr /></b>";

require("./postconnect.php");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM original ORDER BY postid ASC");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

$numrows = $numrows-1;

$sql = "SELECT postername FROM original ORDER BY postid ASC"; // select only the postername field from the table "original"
$result = mysql_query($sql); // process the query

$name_array = array(); // start an array

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // cycle through each record returned
  $name_array[] = "".$row['postername'].""; // get the postername field and add to the array above
}

$sql = "SELECT post FROM original ORDER BY postid ASC"; // select only the post field from the table "original"
$result = mysql_query($sql); // process the query

$post_array = array(); // start an array

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // cycle through each record returned
  $post_array[] = "".$row['post'].""; // get the post field and add to the array above
}

$sql = "SELECT posterside FROM original ORDER BY postid ASC"; // select only the posterside field from the table "original"
$result = mysql_query($sql); // process the query

$side_array = array(); // start an array

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // cycle through each record returned
  $side_array[] = "".$row['posterside'].""; // get the posterside field and add to the array above
}

$sql = "SELECT likes FROM original ORDER BY postid ASC"; // select only the likes field from the table "original"
$result = mysql_query($sql); // process the query

$likes_array = array(); // start an array

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // cycle through each record returned
  $likes_array[] = "".$row['likes'].""; // get the likes field and add to the array above
}

$i=$numrows;

for($i;$i>=0;$i--) {

    if ($side_array[$i]==1) {
        $color="red";
    }
    elseif ($side_array[$i]==2) {
        $color="blue";  
    }
    elseif ($side_array[$i]==3) {
        $color="green"; 
    }

    echo "<form action='./memberhag.php' method='post'>
            <table>
            <tr>
              <td><font color='$color'>$name_array[$i]</font> - $post_array[$i]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='submit' name='likebtn' value='Like' /> <font color=$color>$name_array[$i]</font> has $likes_array[$i] likes!</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>";

    if ($_POST['likebtn']) {

            $numlikes = $likes_array[$i];
        $numlikes = $numlikes + 1;      
        mysql_query("UPDATE original SET likes = '$numlikes' WHERE postername = '$name_array[$i]'");


    }
}

?>
```

This has had me stumped for quite a while... I've even tried using a while loop instead of a for loop.

Comment: Try to formulate "like(this)" so you need to pass as well what *this*  is. Then it works.

Comment: I'm upvoting because I think it's awesome you are self teaching, what we all are probably doing.  Good luck!  As it stands now, your code is ugly, I will try to clean your SQL statements up some, for fun.

Comment: I'm with @Dale - there are a lot of issues here, but we _really_ like it when someone gives it a good go before asking a question! `:)`

Comment: (I'll edit into my answer some general things you can do to improve your code).

Comment: Just to add some input, you should almost certainly be indexing the likes by user in a table, perhaps called "likes" that has a foreign key for the id of the user who "liked" and a foreign key for [whatever]. The reason for this is because this way if you delete a user, the "like" count will adjust. When finding the number of likes, you just do a count on likes for [whatever]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having lots of forms to do this is one possible solution, but I'd be inclined to have just one form, and several buttons. The primary problem seems to be that, as you say, you've called the buttons the same thing, which means you have no way to determine which one has been pressed.

A *very basic* fix is to do this:

```
<input type='submit' name='likebtn_{$i}' value='Like' />
```

That will at least give you an ordinal number you can use to differentiate between buttons. However it is probably better for you to loop through your `posts` in this loop, so you can do this (assuming you have a primary key called `id` in this table:

```
<input type='submit' name='likebtn_{$post['id']}' value='Like' />
```

Ah yes, and when you fix your `POST` section (i.e. the bit when someone pushes a 'like' button) you'll need to read what's in $_POST and parse out what's been pushed. To help debug this, temporarily add this into your post handler:

```
print_r($_POST); exit();
```

That will give you the output you need to decode (check that it is different for each post like). You'll also need to change your `if` statement to detect posts; change this:

```
if ($_POST['likebtn']) {
```

to:

```
if ($_POST) {
```

This is necessary as you now don't have a single name to detect, so we just now detect whether the array `$_POST` contains anything (if it does, we know this is a post operation). Inside this, put the `print_r()` above, to see what's inside it.

Now, here are some things you can do to improve your code:

- It isn't clear what the table `original` does, so I'd probably rename that.
- You seem to have several queries from this table, when you've already done `SELECT * FROM original` - so there are too many queries here
- Bear in mind that in a system like this, you'll probably need other tables, such as who has done the "like" (maybe called `user`)
- Rather than the `for` loop, switch that to a while loop over your posts table.
- Try not to put large blocks of HTML in `echo "x"` statements, as it gets difficult to debug after a while. It is probably better to break out of PHP mode, and use simple loops and variable outputs in HTML mode.

Edit, in response to your comment:

> Ok, I did the if ($_POST) { print_r } and got Array ( [likebtn_4] => Like ) for one of the posts. :-) – Jeremy

Great! OK, try something like this:

```
if ($_POST) {
    $find = 'likebtn_';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $likeKey = (int) str_replace($key, $find, '');
        if ($likeKey) {
            // If this runs, do your update against row $likeKey
            // Note that I've forced it to be an int, to avoid security issues
        }
    }
}
```

Above all, try to understand *why* this works. Do some reading around it if necessary. I've essentially looped through the *associative array* of the post operation, and tested each key (i.e. element name) to see if it contains the string "likebtn_". If it does, I convert the remainder to an integer, which you can then use in an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: I appreciate all the support! I've discovered that this is not an easy thing to teach yourself (which is why I am now on here). I just tried using the name='likebtn_{$i}' code. The display clearly refreshes, but my MySQL database values didn't change. :/ It's like it does not recognize it as a button or something if I put a variable in the name???

Comment: @Jeremy: have you used 'view source' in your browser to check that the generated HTML for each button is different? Paste it up at pastie.org so we can take a look.

Comment: Also, I've changed the `post` handler code - see above ^. And, don't be afraid to put in your own echo/exit statements temporarily to see what variable has what value at each point `:)`.

Comment: rather than doing things this way, I'd be much more inclined to use jQuery combined with a RESTful request

Comment: @Evan - heh, I think that might be jumping ahead a little. Basics first, I think `:-D`

Comment: If he's doing this purely as a learning exercise.. then perhaps, but parsing ids out of request variable names makes me sad

Comment: Just viewed source. It is changing the name of each button to likebtn_6, likebtn_5, etc. and I edited the statement that checks for button clicks to read "if ($_POST['likebtn_{$i}']) {" but every time I have any variable in the name my database does not change. And if I don't have a variable in there, then every "original" post gets a like added to it.

Comment: Hahaha, yeah, if I can do this without Java I would like to... One new language at a time if I can :-)

Comment: @Evan - I don't see why it should. There's no need to add the brittleness of JS to a simple problem, and in any case JS libraries obscure the low-level concepts that one needs to learn. Equally I could have gone down the route of one form per button, so that the button id could be obtained from the query string, but parsing a request array for dynamically named elements is perfectly acceptable, imo. `:)`

Comment: @Jeremy: "It is changing the name of each button to likebtn_6, likebtn_5" - excellent, that's the first part done! But you need to change that `if` statement to just `if ($_POST) {` as I previously explained. Then add the `print_r` and `exit` statements in there, and see what is inside :)

Comment: @Jeremy: (Your way would work, but you'd need to change your `UPDATE` statement to use the value of `$i`. Echo it to the screen so you can see exactly what would be executed on the database, and change it accordingly if necessary).

Comment: I don't know if I agree that you should start out with only one language, especially in the case of PHP/javascript. I started out with very basic PHP/MySQL stuff, and I feel like I would have progressed faster if I'd focussed on all aspects of web programming at the same time. It's fine to keep things "basic" - but just remember that you should ultimately aim high and make an effort to use the latest and greatest methods for accomplishing objectives, since there's a reason most (sane) people are using approaches like jQuery/REST instead of basic forms for tasks like this.

Comment: Ok, I did the if ($_POST) { print_r and got Array ( [likebtn_4] => Like ) for one of the posts. :-)

Comment: How do I go about changing my UPDATE statement to use the value of $i?

Comment: Honestly, stop.  You need to clarify and shorten your code.  You are going to come back to this after you've added 1000 more useless lines and want to shoot yourself.

Comment: Well, I think I'm going to get some sleep. I'll take another look at your advice tomorrow night, and maybe I'll finally crack this thing! Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: @Jeremy - see my update. I've added some code to strip out the integer key you can use in an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Added this code and got it working! Thank you everyone for all the help!
    if ($_POST) {
        $find = 'likebtn_';
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
      $likeKey = preg_replace ( '#\D*?(\d+(\.\d+)?)\D*#', '$1', $key ); 
            if ($i == $likeKey) {
       $newlikes = $likes_array[$i]+1;
       echo "Like added!";
                mysql_query("UPDATE original SET likes = '$newlikes' WHERE postername = '$name_array[$i]'");
       mysql_query("UPDATE original SET likenames = '$likenames_array[$i], $username' WHERE postername = '$name_array[$i]'");
            }
       }
    }

Comment: Can't wait to get better at this so I can help others the way you guys have helped me! Much appreciation all!

Comment: No probs. Don't forget to tick your preferred answer, and don't worry if this question closes as 'too broad'. Glad you got it working!

Comment: Thank you very much halfer! Preferred answer has been ticked!

Answer (score 2):

There is literally no differing logic in any one of these queries. Therefore the obvious (read only) thing to do is combine them into one statement.  When writing code, write as little as possible.  Believe it or not, this will greatly improve the quality of your code.  Do not sacrifice clarity to achieve this goal though, sometimes clarity is expressed in fewer lines, sometimes it is not.

I'm going to assume your db, and your ONLY table has this form:

```
|postername|post|posterside|likes|
```

This means that EVERY row in the original table has corresponding columns described like above.

So....

```
if(!empty($_POST) && !!$_POST['likebtn']) {
    //Do your likebtn stuff here.
}
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM colums ORDER BY postid ASC";
$result = mysqli->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    switch($row[2]) {
        case 1:
             $color = "red";
             break;
        case 2:
             $color = "blue";
             break;
        case 3:
             $color = "green";
             break;
        default:
            //Handle when this case doesn't match
     }
//The rest of your table would go hear, remember that $row[0] is the corresponding
//postername for said row.  You will loop through rows until there are no more.
//Study Mysql injection, you are in danger of it now.  Good luck
}
```

Comment: +1 for using a non-deprecated db library `:)`. And yes, SQL injection; I suspect we'll get to that later.

Comment: My database has columns posterid, postername, posterside, postid, likes, likenames, post, date. In that order. The idea was to save the id and name of the original poster, their side, an auto incremented id for their post, the number of likes the post got, the names of the users that liked it, the post itself, and the date.

Comment: that is fine, start counting from 0, $row[7] corresponds to date.  The switch looks like it is still ok.  The point is group as much logic together as you can.  Here, there is no logic, so you might as well grab the whole row by using *.